# How to separate string with comma using concat function in mysql?

Tags: mysql

code:

```
$insert = "UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = CONCAT_WS(',', '', '$string') WHERE something = 'something';
```

In this query I have an variable $string where I want when I click on submit button it store data like ,a,b,c,d but now what happen when I click on submit button it update my table with ,a and doing same process at second time it update ,b but I want ,a,b so how can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there !

If you want to append a new string to your field here is the query :

```
$insert = "UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = CONCAT_WS(',', FIELD , '$string') WHERE something = 'something';
```

Because if you look how work 
 CONCAT_WS ([W3school link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat_ws.asp))

it's CONCAT_WS(separator, expression1, expression2, expression3,...)
here expression1 is the FIELD you want to update and expression2 the $string